# Function call returns Promise {_U: 0, _V: 0, _W: null, _X: null} instead of true or false

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, promise

I am trying to call my [NetInfo](https://github.com/react-native-netinfo/react-native-netinfo) function like this on a separate file:

```
import NetInfo from '@react-native-community/netinfo';

export default class checkNetwork {
  static async isNetworkAvailable() {
    const response = await NetInfo.fetch();
    return response.isConnected;
  }
}
```

**Redux File**

```
const connectionStatus = async () => {
  await checkNetwork.isNetworkAvailable();
};
const isConnected = connectionStatus();
console.log('status of network >>', isConnected);
```

Instead of `true` or `false` it returned a promise `Promise {_U: 0, _V: 0, _W: null, _X: null}`.

How do I fix this to return a boolean?

Comment: try `const isConnected = await connectionStatus();`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Async function always returns a promise and to resolve it you need to await it, so simply add await in front of `connectionStatus` function.

```
const isConnected = await connectionStatus();
```

If you are using `react saga` ( generators ) to achieve it, you can use `yield` instead of `await`.

```
const isConnected = yield connectionStatus();
```